# Powershell- get most recently created certificate

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

I am working on a automation to get the most recently created certificate and if the expiry date is less than 30 days, try to create a new certificate to use it for my sql instance. I am facing a challenge in filtering the output.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine\My | fl *

PSDrive                  : Cert
PSProvider               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate
PSIsContainer            : False
EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)}

PSDrive                  : Cert
PSProvider               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate
PSIsContainer            : False
EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Remote Desktop Authentication (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.54.1.2), Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)}
```

I want only the 1st certificate in my output which is server Authentication and I dont want the 2nd one used for RDP.

Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -eq 'Server Authentication'} | Sort-Object Notafter -Descending | select -First 1

I am not sure how to use where-object to filter only the most recent server authentication certificate in my output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add "Select-Object -Property *" to get all properties including dates and then sort by date.

Comment: Hi @jdweng- Getting the expiry date is not a problem. I am doing Sort-Object Notafter -Descending. My challenge is I want to apply filter on EnhancedKeyUsageList to get only the most recently created Server Authentication certificate.  I am trying to avoid the most recently created RDP certificate here.

Comment: Your filter seems to be correct, except that it's conceptually clearer to say `$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -contains 'Server Authentication'`, given that `$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList` is a _list_. There seem to be only two timestamp properties, `.NotBefore` and `.NotAfter` - how do they relate to a certificate's _creation_ date, if at all? If you're looking for those expiring _soonest_, omit `-Descending`.

Comment: Hi @mklement0 - Thanks for your tip which helped me figure it out. Both the certificate's EnhancedKeyUsageList contains 'Server Authentication' so -contains returns both of them. I used -notcontains to retrieve only the certificate with 'Server Authentication' which works well.

  Get-ChildItem -Recurse Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.EnhancedKeyUsageList.FriendlyName -notcontains 'Remote Desktop Authentication'}